# Selecting data where there's less than 10 linked rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have 2 tables in mySQL Database:

- **Proxy**: `ID, host, port, user, pw`
- **Account**: `proxyID, column`

I want to get all the Proxy's which ID's appear in Account table `<=10` times.

`SELECT count(ProxyId) from Account`

Don't know how to continue from here and get the Proxy values that have less then 10 appears.

Comment: Well, if you want that result, then you have probably attempted something in SQL.  Please include that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.Id from proxy a, account b
where a.ID = b.proxyId
group by a.ID
having count(*) <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Proxy AS p JOIN Account AS a ON p.ID = a.proxyID
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10
```